# Swift SearchBar- [general] Connection to daemon was invalidated

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

I just added a ui searchbar to my program, and every time i rerun the program I get the error- 
[general] Connection to daemon was invalidated
Despite this, my app is able to run perfectly and I can't seem to tell what is wrong.

Does anyone know what this means and how I could fix this?

If you'd like to to take a look at my code, please let me know and I'll clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

I am running my app on a physical device and I have the same issue. Looking at other threads on Stack Overflow, it appears that this is just a glitch in Xcode and probably not an issue on your part.

If you are using a physical device, try running it on a simulator - the error shouldn't appear (at least it didn't for me)

Comment: its a funny error, and it remains regardless of wether I run It on simulator or physical device